# How to upload images in react via api?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

Today I saw a number of tutorials on how to upload photos in react via the api.

I did everything, tried all the methods. But in the end I get stuck.

(During the whole explanation I will focus only on the features of the image upload)
In Models I have groups and variable -

```
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile ImageFile {get; set; }
```

In api I get

```
  [Route ("Add")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post (Group group)
```

And I have in state-

```
  const initialFieldValues ​​= {
        GroupName: '',
        GroupAbout: '',
        imageName: '',
        imageSrc: defaultImageSrc,
        imageFile: null
    }
    const [values, setValues] = useState (initialFieldValues)
```

When changing the image has a function-

```
const handleImg = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files [0]) {
        
      

            let imageFile = e.target.files [0];
            const reader = new FileReader ();
            reader.onload = x => {
                setValues ​​({
                    ... values,
                    imageFile,
                    imageSrc: x.target.result
                })
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL (imageFile)
            SetDisplayImg ("block");
        }
        else {
            setValues ​​({
                ... values,
                imageFile: null,
                imageSrc: defaultImageSrc
            })
        }

    };
```

And when submitting the form

```
    const handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault ()
            const formData = new FormData ()
                .append ('groupImage', values.imageFile)
            addOrEdit (formData)
    }



    const addOrEdit = (formData) => {
        axios.post ('api / groups / add', formData) .catch (error => {
            console.log (error.response.data);
            console.log (error.response.status);
            console.log (error.response.headers);
        });
        
    }
```

**In this code** -makes **error 415** (even regardless of uploading the image but, even if I put it only other variables that get stringed and work normally.)

**If I add [FromForm]** in the api it **does not respond to me**, i.e. it does not write me an error message nor does it reach the api (I checked in debugging)

If I **change the axios** to
const obj = {'groupImage': values.imageFile
}

```
    axios.post ('api / groups / add', obj) .catch (error =>
```

I get an error message 400-
**"The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ .groupImage**

And if **I send the value from state**
axios.post ('api / groups / add', values)

I get an error message **System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'. Path: $ .imageFile | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 6939781.**
---> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'.

Anything I try to fix, it causes another error, I'm really at a loss.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>.append ('groupImage', values.imageFile)
```

Firstly, please make sure the `key` of your `formdata` object can match your model class property's name.

```
formData.append('imageName', values.imageName);
//...

//it should be imageFile, not groupImage
formData.append('imageFile', values.imageFile);
```

Besides, please apply the `[FromForm]` attribute to action parameter, like below.

```
public void Post([FromForm]Group group)
{
    //...
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: תודה רבה, עזרת לי מאוד. תוכל בבקשה לעזור לי גם מה הטעות שלי בשאלה: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692777/how-to-login-in-react-and-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

Usually a 415 means you aren't setting the right Content-Type header.  Does the API you are trying to upload to mention acceptable types or encodings it expects?

Comment: I do not know. I tried all the options I thought could be and each one gave me another error. Could you perhaps help me know what he expects to receive and that I do not give? If there is any information missing from what I gave, write to me and I will edit the question. Thank you